# Delete from a long list of options

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to delete some rows from MyTable and I typically use a "Delete From MyTable" and then a "where" statement.  I now have about 100 different criteria for deleting rows based on one column and using the "or" will take forever. can I just use a list to shorten this up. An attempt at an example follows:

```
GroupInitials 

ABC

DEF

GHI

JKL

MNO

PQR

STU

VWX

AEF

UYT
```

I have been doing the following

```
Delete from MyTable

Where GroupInitials = 'ABC' or GroupInitials ='GHI' or GroupInitials = 'STU' ...
```

I have a very long list of things to delete, so is there any way I can simply list these instead of using 100 "or" statements

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `IN` predicate:

```
Delete 
from MyTable
Where GroupInitials IN('ABC', 'GHI', 'STU' ...);
```

Or you can write these values in a temp table and delete them using the same way:

```
Delete 
from MyTable
Where GroupInitials IN(SELECT name from temptable);
```

and for this way you can `JOIN` instead of `IN`.